# Copy Constructors And Assignment Operator in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor

When I was studying constructors in  C++, I came up things that are hard to fully understand for me. One is when we create an object of a class (say `class Point`), if we didn't write a constructor for ourselves, the default constructor gets called.(same for copy constructor I think)

```
Point p2 = p1;
```

I get that in this situation default copy constructor get called, but what if i do that:

```
Point p1;
p1.setX(3);
p2.setY(2);

Point p2;

p2 = p1;
```

This still works, but I suppose the default copy constructor doesn't get called here, because I think constructor gets called when object is created. So how does that assignment work in the second case?

Other than that, I was wondering when we write our own copy constructors(`ClassName (const ClassName &old_obj);` or so). Is there a difference between two examples below or it is just syntactic sugar?

```
Point p3(p1);
```

and

```
Point p3 = p1;
```

And in the second example, why does the program infer that we are passing `p1` as an argument to copy constructor while we didn't write it after `p3` inside parantheses?

Also, when we create an object of a class that takes arguments to its construcor, we use parentheses to pass data as arguments. But when it comes to default constructor (**even if we wrote our own**) we don't use parentheses at all and create the object like that:

```
Point p1;
```

and not like that:

```
Point p1(); // even if we defined our default constructor like "Point() {}"
```

What is the reason for that? Does the program know not to create the default constructor for us?

Comment: The last example is not a default constructor, it's a function declaration for a function called `p1` which takes no arguments and returns a `Point`. Hence that's why you can't use it to create a `Point` called `p1`. This is called the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Have a look at [Default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) and [Copy constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and [Member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization). And no, the technical nature the material is presented in isn't always the easiest for new programmers to digest (don't worry, it gets easier). For your last point (no pun intended), `Point p1;` declares an instance of `class Point`, while `Point pi();` creates a function.

Comment: Oh okay, the last one declares a function that returns the type `Point`. I'll take a look at those links too.

Comment: @alexmoran also be aware of that defining one constructor might automatically remove the automatic presence of the others.

Answer (score 1):

I assume a default Point implementation here.

> When I was studying constructors in C++, I came up things that are hard to fully understand for me. One is when we create an object of a class (say class Point), if we didn't write a constructor for ourselves, the default constructor gets called.(same for copy constructor I think)
>
> Point p2 = p1;
>
> I get that in this situation default copy constructor get called, but what if i do that:

True

> Point p1;
> p1.setX(3);
> p2.setY(2);
>
> Point p2;
>
> p2 = p1;
> This still works, but I suppose the default copy constructor doesn't get called here, because I think constructor gets called when object is created. So how does that assignment work in the second case?

True. The assignment operator is used. The copy constructor is only used when a new Point object is created. In practice, if you have a copy constructor you should have a copy assignment operator with a
machting implementation.

> Other than that, I was wondering when we write our own copy constructors(ClassName (const ClassName &old_obj); or so). Is there a difference between two examples below or it is just syntactic sugar?

You would write your own copy constructor if there is something special about it. Maybe a member should not be copied for some reason. Maybe a member cannot copied with a copy constructor/assignment constructor and you have to call a non-standard CloneThis method.
If all members are copyable and all members should be copied, just use = default.

(I will leave move assignment/move construction out of this)

> Point p3(p1);
> and
>
> Point p3 = p1;
> And in the second example, why does the program infer that we are passing p1 as an argument to copy constructor while we didn't write it after p3 inside parantheses?

Since C++11, it is guaranteed to be syntactic sugar. They are both guaranteed to call the copy constructor. The alternative interpretation would be to first call the default constructor for p3 and then call the assignment operator to assign the values of p1 to p3. That is clearly wasteful and might not be even possible if p3 is not default-constructible.

> Also, when we create an object of a class that takes arguments to its construcor, we use parentheses to pass data as arguments. But when it comes to default constructor (even if we wrote our own) we don't use parentheses at all and create the object like that:
>
> Point p1;
> and not like that:
>
> Point p1(); // even if we defined our default constructor like "Point() {}"
> What is the reason for that? Does the program know not to create the default constructor for us?

You can write Point p1; or you can write Point p1{};

You can write Point p1(), but that means declaring a function p1 without arguments, which returns a Point.
However, modern compilers will give you a warning about the third variant because it is a common mistake to make.

The modern recommendation is to use {} because it is more uniform.
Point p1{};
Point p2{1, 1};

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's helpful, but one thing I am trying to understand is: When we are trying to assign two class objects we have previously created, CPP is able to understand we are telling it to copy the variable values one by one from one to another? (If object's been already created, and no copy constructors called?)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand: The copy constructor/copy assignment, which is generated by default, copies the members one by one.

Comment: My question is, the assignment operator isn't just used for primitive data types. If it's used with class objects etc. copy assignment operator does that?

Comment: Think about it that way. C++ tries hard to make it easy to add new types which feel "primitive" like a string class with assignment, or a class for complex numbers (in the standard) or a class unlimited domain integers. All should feel natural to the user. That is why general operator overloading is a thing in C++. Value semantics in general (aka assignment operators and constructors) became much more important in C++11/14/17. Value semantics are often safer and often not (much) more expensive than dealing with pointers and references.